# What defines a tool as a "compiler"

Tags: terminology, compilers

I've been trying to figure out what technically makes a tool or program a *compiler*.

For example, I know that [gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/) will compile source code to object files or assembly, hence transforming a programming language to a different form by breaking it down into "words" with some lexer and reading the "grammar" of the words with some parser, and finally compiling it.

But is the term *compiler* limited to transforming specifically programming languages?

For example, there's a tool called [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) that will read all of the documentation from source code files, break them down, and generate output based on the documentation. Is this considered to be a *compiler*?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A compiler translates code written in one programming language into code in another language -- normally, with the semantics of the output code being the same as the input code (or with a strong relationship).

Personally, if you asked me to use the word strictly, I wouldn't call Doxygen a compiler.  The output isn't executable code, and doesn't have anything like the same semantics as the input source code.

See also [Wikipedia's definition/explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler).

That said, there are many situations where we use a word loosely, when from context it will be understood what we're referring to -- so I'm not sure how useful it will be to look for a super-precise definition of the word.  If the specific definition is important in your writing, then it might be best to define how you plan to use the term.

Comment: Note that by compilers often only omit assembly code, not object files. Tools like `gcc` are actually a "driver" that call the compiler (`cc1`), assembler (`as`), and linker (`ld`) as needed.

Comment: Hm. What would we call a tool that converts Markdown to HTML? For me, it would be a compiler but neither language is a programming one, nor do they have formal semantics. So both our answers miss the point?

Comment: @Raphael, good question!  I probably wouldn't consider that a compiler, but rather would put it under the category of 'using the word loosely is fine as long as everyone will understand what we mean'.. but I have no idea if my usage is objectively correct or represents any kind of consensus.

Comment: There's also the term "transpiler".

Answer (score 4):

Say you have two (programming) languages $A$ and $B$. For the sake of simplicity, let the "effect" (output, side effects, ...) of a program  be given by a language-specific functions $\operatorname{effect}$. Then, a function $c$ is a compiler from $A$ to $B$ if (and only if)

$\qquad \operatorname{effect}_A(p) = \operatorname{effect}_B(c(p))$

for all $p \in A$.

Note how this is more general than what D.W. proposes: I do not distinguish types of languages; I only require that languages have semantics, i.e. they are designed to compute something. I would call an algorithm that translates regular expressions to finite automata (or vice versa) a compiler, too.

*Site note:* the existence of compilers between any two Turing-complete languages has been established in computability theory; [admissible numberings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admissible_numbering) can be computably converted into one another.